# Azure Blob Storage Lifecycle Management - embedded folders

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently trying to implement lifecycle management on a container where i have embeded folders as follows:

```
container1/1/test/done_filename.txt
container1/1/processed/complete_filename.txt
container1/1/wip_filename.txt
```

i tried creating a rule filter to delete files under the test folder that start with done however i waited 48 hours and it's still not removed.

```
Rule filter:
delete after 1 day 
Prefix Match:
file with this prefix: container1/1/test/done_
```

All samples I see from microsoft and online only mention "myContainer/prefix", am i to understand that the lifecycle management feature doesn't support subfolders/full paths? do all files have to be within the the root of the container? or what am i doing wrong here.

Updated showing rule definition:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I expect the above to delete any file under "container1/1/test/" that starts with "done_" but the file is still there when i check after a few days even though the file has not been modified.

Comment: have you enabled rule? and blob type is block blob or append blob? It's better if you can show us the complete rule definition?

Comment: Thanks for the response, these are all block blobs and the rule is set to act on block blobs, yes the rule is enabled. i've updated the post to show the rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/154361/view.html

When you are using selected networks because of security restrictions like we do then correct solution is to enable “Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account” under Networking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled the rule, then your policy and prefix match are ok.

You need to check some settings which can block the `blob delete operation`:

1.Make sure you can manually delete these blobs. You can try to delete one of them manually. Why we need to do that? If you have [leased these blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob) or [set immutability policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutability-policies-manage?tabs=azure-portal), the delete operation are not allowed.

2.Check the settings in Networking pane of your storage account. And make sure you select the option "Allow access from All networks":

[image]